# D3.JS: Zig zag line on y-axis between zero and start value

Tags: d3.js

I've modified the `y.domain` of my D3 bar chart so it starts at a value above zero. However, I want to add a little "zig zag line" to indicate this, as in the picture below.

[image: Chart with zig zag line]

How could I do this in D3? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just hack this on by adding another path to the y axis:

```
// define how much space you'd like to create the axis "break" in
var axisBreakSpace = 50;

// Add the X Axis, with the space
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + axisBreakSpace) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis, normally
var yG = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

// add the zigzags path
yG.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(){
    var numZags = 10, // number of zigzags
        zagDist = (axisBreakSpace - 5) / numZags; // y distance on each zig or zag, -5 is a bit of space to finish it off

    // build the path at
    var curZig = height,
        d = "M0," + curZig;
    for (var i = 0; i < numZags; i++){
      curZig += zagDist;
      d += (i % 2 === 0) ? " L10," + curZig : " L-10," + curZig;
    }

    // finish it off to the x-axis
    d += " L0," + (height + axisBreakSpace);
    return d;
  });
```

---

Full working code sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /* set the CSS */
  
  body {
    font: 12px Arial;
  }
  
  path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {
        top: 30,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      axisBreakSpace = 50;

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width])
              .domain([0, 10]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])
              .domain([200,1000]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    // Define the line
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
      });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.range(10).map(function(d){
      return {
        x: d,
        y: (Math.random() * 800) + 200
      }
    });

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + axisBreakSpace) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
      
    // Add the Y Axis
    var yG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
    
    yG.append("path")
      .attr("d", function(){
        var numZags = 10,
            zagDist = (axisBreakSpace - 5) / numZags;

        var curZig = height,
            d = "M0," + curZig;
        for (var i = 0; i < numZags; i++){
          curZig += zagDist;
          d += (i % 2 === 0) ? " L10," + curZig : " L-10," + curZig;
        }
        d += " L0," + (height + axisBreakSpace);
        return d;
      });

    
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest and most concise way to do this given D3's limitations, thanks!

Comment: @Algorithm_NL, limitations?!  `d3` met your requirement with 13 lines of code.  :)

Comment: Haha, touché. Really love D3, just meant that this is not a built-in feature ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would create some data and pass it to the D3 library. Something similar to this :

```
var data = [{
x1: xAxisSTARTPOINTX, //start
y1; xAxisSTARTPOINTY,
x2: firstXPointOnZigZag, 
y2; firstYPointOnZigZag},{
.
.
. },{
x1: lastXPointOnZigZag, //end
y1; lastYPointOnZigZag,
x2: yAxisSTARTPOINTX, 
y2; yAxisSTARTPOINTY}

}]
```

The values you put between will be the points on the zig zag which you can make up/generate.

Then pass this to this :

```
d3.select(container).data(data).enter().append('path')
.attr('x1', function(d){ return d.x1})
.attr('y1', function(d){ return d.y1})
.attr('x2', function(d){ return d.x2})
.attr('y2', function(d){ return d.y2})
.style('stroke','black');
```

You could generate the points yourself so you can change how many 'zigzags' you want by changing 'i' in the for loop.

A function to create points, something similar to this :

```
    function createPoints(xAxisStartPoint, yAxisStartPoint){ //pass two arrays

        var xAxisStartX = xAxisStartPoint[0], //xAxisStartPointX
        xAxisStartY = xAxisStartPoint[1], //xAxisStartPointY
        yAxisStartX = yAxisStartPoint[0], //xAxisStartPointX
        yAxisStartY = yAxisStartPoint[1]; //yAxisStartPointY

    var difference = xAxisStartY-yAxisStartY; //gets the difference between xAxis and yAxis to make sure the points are equal distance apart.

        var allPoints = []; //array to populate with points
        var numberOfPoints = 4; //number of zigzags
        var movement = 20; //movement left and right

        for(var i=0;i<=numberOfPoints;i++){
           var thisPoint = [];
              if(i===0){ //push xAxisStartPoint
                 thisPoint.push({
                    x:xAxisStartX,
                    y:xAxisStartY
                 })
              } else if(i===4){ //push yAxisStartPoint
                 thisPoint.push({
                   x:yAxisStartX,
                   y:yAxisStartY
              })
              } else {
                  thisCalcPointX;

                  if(i%2 > 0){ //if i is odd move left
                      thisCalcPointX = xAxisStartX-movement; //move point to the left
                  } else { //if it's even move right
                      thisCalcPointX = xAxisStartX+movement; //move point to the right
                  }
                  thisCalcPointY = xAxisStartY + difference/i; //move point up from xAxis start point at equal distance between xAxis and yAxis
                  thisPoint.push({
                   x: xAxisStartX,
                   y: thisCalcPointY
              })


        }
    allPoints.push(thisPoint); //push this point to array of points


        }


        return allPoints; //return the points
        }

//then pass this to create the path 

     var xAxisStart = [ xAxisStartX, xAxisStartY];
     var yAxisStart= [ yAxisStartX, yAxisStartY];
     var dataPoints = createPoints([xAxisStart, yAxisStart])

     d3.select(container).data(dataPoints).enter().append('path')
         .attr('x1', function(d){ return d.x1})
         .attr('y1', function(d){ return d.y1})
         .attr('x2', function(d){ return d.x2})
         .attr('y2', function(d){ return d.y2})
         .style('stroke','black');
```

Above code is not tested and just done on the fly, may need playing with, but the logic should work to create random points either side between both axis.